# How to Change date format in hive

Tags: timestamp, hive

I have one table in hive with column "dates"(String) and value as "5/29/2014 11:58:02 AM".
I need to change the datatype from string to timestamp to process the data,I have created temporary table and trying to insert data from the original table:

```
create table temp as select 
 level,
 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dates,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')) as newTime,
 source,
 eventid,
 task,
 description,
 category 
from logs;
```

It didn't work .How to solve this?
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the unix_timestamp as below and see if this works.

```
unix_timestamp(dates, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a')
```

To know more about date formatting check this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

PS: I have not tried this as I do not have a hive setup in front of me now.

Answer (score 1):

I hope understanding of this below example may solve the problem

> create table ex(id string,**timing string**,status string)
>   row format delimited
>   fields terminated by '\t'
>   lines terminated by '\n'
>   stored as textfile;
>
> load data local inpath '/home/jayanthsn/Jay.txt' into table ex;

o/p:

User01      03-09-2015 10:00    logintime

User02      04-09-2015 10:00    logintime

User03      05-09-2015 10:00    logintime

(Bring the date format as it is with string datatype.)

**Later create one more table by making that column as timestamp**.

> create table ex1(id string,**timing timestamp**,status string)
>   row format delimited
>   fields terminated by '\t'
>   lines terminated by '\n'
>   stored as textfile;
>
> insert into table ex1 select id,**from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timing,'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'))**,status from ex;

o/p:

User01      2015-03-09 10:00:00 logintime

User02      2015-04-09 10:00:00 logintime

User03      2015-05-09 10:00:00 logintime

now you can get the standard timestamp format.